# Problems identifing which page is active after loading same html page multiple times in same document

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have a main page that looks like this:

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content1"/>
  <div id="content2"/>
</div>
```

I am using ajax to dynamically load content1 and content2 from the same file (say Content.aspx).

```html
<div id="content">
  <input id="content_data" type="hidden" value="whatever"/>
</div>
```

Since the html in content1 and content2 share elements id's, jquery always finds content1 elements:

$("#content_data").val();

If however I use the parent div I can get the data I want:

$("#content1").find("#content_data").val();

The problem:

Given a single Content.aspx page, how can the page (on the client side) know which container div it is is?

On Page_load (server side) I know the page index which I can save in a hidden field on the page but on the client side when I run jquery to get the hidden index I don't know which parent div to look in - unless I'm overlooking something (quite possible) it's a catch-22 situation.

If I can get a hold of an element I can query it's parent and determine which content div it is in, but I can't get that far, because to get an element I need to use jquery and it always finds elements in the first content div. So client side I can't tell where I am from the start.

First of all is this a good way to accomplish what I want, two or more divs loaded with identical pages (but different data) existing in the same document?

An alternative I thought of would be to have multipe content.aspx pages, content1.apsx, content2.aspx, and so on...each identical but with with unique element id's based on its ordinal position.

I feel this would be much 'safer' but would require more maintenance to keep all the pages in sync as things change.

In case you're wondering, the specific use case I'm trying to accomplish is having multiple customer pages open simultaneously in a one-page web application.

Comment: if id's are the issue, then use a class, if that's what the question's/problem's about

Comment: this is wrong $("#content1").find("#content_data").val(); from the snippet, content_data is in content not content1

Comment: Well, its a difficult problem to explain, the problem I'm having is the javascript I run after the page is loaded to do the work of the page (load data, for example) does not 'know' what page it should be working on.  The javascript is common to all pages, even if I include it in the individual pages it is the same.

Comment: Bindrid - yes, I should have been more clear, it is a child of content1 (and content2 for that matter) because I plan on loading content via ajax into content1 and content2.

Comment: OK, starting to think more clearly on this, the 'active' div will not be hidden, so I could mark the active div with a class ('active', perhaps!) then the javascript called for blur, click, etc, events on that page can look for the active div children to work on...

Comment: Resolved - seemingly, in 2 steps, first, on ajax page load I make id's unique by replacing id="somename_UNIQUE" with "somename_n" when n is my index., second, I determine the currently active parent div  index by looking for the 'active' class.  Seems to work fine and not run afoul of potential duplicate id problems.

Answer (score 0):

While hesitant to answer my own question this is the solution I'm using and it works and it does not suffer from any of the pitfalls I ran into trying to maintain an external indicator of the currently active page which was prone to timing issues when ajax loads were slow and the user clicked to load another content div...

My solution is to have a unique page/javascript for each div but since the pages/javascript are 100% identical except for the id's (and data models) I maintain only one copy of the page on the server, with the javascript included in the head (for easy access), and all identifiers are suffixed with a unique keyword that is texttually replaced with the ordnal index of the parent div on ajax success.

So my content page looks like this:

```
<head>
  <script>
    kendo.bind($("#clientUNIQUE"), clientViewModel[UNIQUE]);    
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="clientUNIQUE">
    content here
  </div>
</body>
```

then on ajax success:

```
result = result.replace(/UNIQUE/g, ndx);
$("#content" + ndx).html(result);
```